# Angular.JS - Event is being triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**Code:**

```
scope.offCanvasShow = function ($event) {
  $('.app-off-canvas-menu').toggleClass('show');
  // Prevents default functionality of a element
  // In this instance, this prevents the anchor from reloading the page on click.
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();

  $(document).one('touchstart click', offCanvasHandler);

  /**
    * Checks to see if the event target isn't .off-canvas-menu or has off-canvas-menu as a parent then removes the
    * show class.
    * @param event - is the event of the function
   */
  function offCanvasHandler(event) {
    console.log('hello');
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.app-off-canvas-menu').length) {
      $('.app-off-canvas-menu').removeClass('show');
      $(document).off('touchstart click', offCanvasHandler);
  } else {
    $(document).one('touchstart click', offCanvasHandler);
  }
  }
};
```

This is a simple off canvas drop down menu. I have this odd problem of bubbling. That I thought I fixed with the `.one()` function.

If you click on the class app-off-canvas-menu a few times and then leave the menu open and click outside of the menu the menu closes which is what I want.

Here is the but, once I clicked outside of the menu it seems that the console log gets run multiple times depending on how many times I've clicked the app-off-canvas-menu hamburger.

Can anyone see anything clearly obvious with my code?

Its worth noting that I am using angular so it might be possible I have to go about this in a different fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you click on the class app-off-canvas-menu a few times and then leave the menu open and click outside of the menu the menu closes which is what I want.

Every time you click on the class you will bind another handler:

```
$(document).one('touchstart click', offCanvasHandler);
```

so when you click outside the element it will execute all those handlers.

From the jQuery website:

> The `.one()` method is identical to `.on()`, except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation.

So you don't bind it once, it only runs once. This might have caused the confusion.

---

Update with code:

```
var isBound = false;
scope.offCanvasShow = function ($event) {
  $('.app-off-canvas-menu').toggleClass('show');
    // Prevents default functionality of a element
    // In this instance, this prevents the anchor from reloading the page on click.
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    if(!isBound) {
      $(document).one('touchstart click', offCanvasHandler);
      isBound = true;
    }

    /**
      * Checks to see if the event target isn't .off-canvas-menu or has off-canvas-menu as a parent then removes the
      * show class.
      * @param event - is the event of the function
     */
    function offCanvasHandler(event) {
      console.log('hello');
      if (!$(event.target).closest('.app-off-canvas-menu').length) {
        $('.app-off-canvas-menu').removeClass('show');
        $(document).off('touchstart click', offCanvasHandler);
    } else {
      $(document).one('touchstart click', offCanvasHandler);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Maybe I've mis-understood but I believe thats  what I want. I only want the .one() function to run once. I'm not to sure what your solution is.

Comment: Legendary, Perfect answer. Thank you